# Metro bundler with Expo dockerized app is not working

Tags: docker, react-native, docker-compose, expo, metro-bundler

I'm trying to dockerize an Expo React Native app so anyone of my team partners could download the repo and then make a `docker-compose up` and without effort have the same expo server running in their computers. 
As far I make it possible to build the container and it is showing the same info it show up when I run it locally on my computer.

[image]

The problem arises when trying to start the metro bundler, url `http://localhost:19002` is inaccessible. That doesn't happen with the port 19001, which is working perfectly.Besides, I tryed scanning the QR code with my iPhone device but it doesn't work neither, because is not finding the docker ip I guess.
I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, and there is not so much information about dockerize expo in the web.

These are my dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
COPY app.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install -g expo-cli

EXPOSE 19000
EXPOSE 19001
EXPOSE 19002

CMD npm i -f && npm start
```

```
version: '3.7' # Specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
   expo: # Name of the frontend service
      container_name: expo-prestadores
      build: ./ # Specify the directory of the Dockerfile
      ports:
         - 19000:19000 # Specify port-forwarding
         - 19001:19001
         - 19002:19002
      volumes: # Mount host path in the container
         - ./:/usr/src/app
         - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Makes sense. Expo DevTools tells you it is running on `localhost` in your container.

This means that in your container the Expo DevTools are only available to `localhost`. Which in turn is only available from within the container itself. No port exposure will help you there. You need to set your port binding in a way that allows outside access. e.g. via the IP of the container in order to allow an expose statement to work.

In short, add the `EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0` environment variable like this

```
version: '3.7' # Specify docker-compose version
services:
   expo: # Name of the frontend service
      container_name: expo-prestadores
      build: ./ # Specify the directory of the Dockerfile
      ports:
         - 19000:19000 # Specify port-forwarding
         - 19001:19001
         - 19002:19002
      volumes: # Mount host path in the container
         - ./:/usr/src/app
         - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      environment:
         - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
```

to your `docker-compose.yml` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks ckaserer, this works but only halfway. The logo of Expo developer tools is showing up in the tab on the browser, but only a black background screen is visible. Besides, I don't know why if in the terminal says Metro bundler will be running on port 19001, then when I search for it, it opens the React Native Debugger tab. I could connect the expo docker with my mobile phone now because I added REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME variable to enviroment in my docker-compose.yml, but it is impossible for me to open the app in a simulator without using the Metro Bundler interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have any idea how to fix the browser issue you just mentioned in the comment above, maybe somebody else is up to the task

Answer (score 6):

To fix the black background screen in the browser as mentioned in previous responses, you must add the REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME environment variable and set it to your computer's local IP address. Then instead of navigating to `localhost:19002` or `0.0.0.0:19002` for the Expo Developer Tools, navigate to `<<HOST LOCAL IP>>:19002` (replacing with your respective IP, of course), and you should see the DevTools working. The QR code on this page should load your app on ExpoGo at the address `<<HOST LOCAL IP>>:19000`.

Your docker-compose.yml should now look like this:

```
version: '3.7' # Specify docker-compose version
services:
   expo: # Name of the frontend service
      container_name: expo-prestadores
      build: ./ # Specify the directory of the Dockerfile
      ports:
         - 19000:19000 # Specify port-forwarding
         - 19001:19001
         - 19002:19002
      volumes: # Mount host path in the container
         - ./:/usr/src/app
         - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      environment:
         - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0 
         - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=<<HOST LOCAL IP>>>
```

Comment: Using the local IP was a savior for me. This expo react native and docker also made me paranoid. Thanks @CJSantee !

Comment: @CJSantee do you know how could I send API requests from the expo app running in one container to another container that has the backend. I am trying to configure nginx but I am stuck.

Comment: Yep local IP saved me as well. The EXPO Go didn't load the app but I resolved that issue by using tunnel connection. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little too late for this but I've come up with a workaround here, once you've implemented the solution given by @ckaserer you can log on to http://0.0.0.0:19002 and select `Tunnel` instead of `LAN` in the connection section just as shown below and run your application on Expo Go App and it'd be fine
[image]