# Expo developer tools open black screen on the browser using Docker as Development Environment

Tags: docker, react-native

I'm trying to dockerize an Expo React Native app in order to have an Development Environment for reuse cases.

At the moment I make it possible to build the container.

http://prntscr.com/rezs9e

The problem is when i go to localhost:19002 trying to access to Expo developer tools it loads the tab image but the window content is a black screen.

http://prntscr.com/reztg5

I find this similar to [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638451/metro-bundler-with-expo-dockerized-app-is-not-working/60643720#60643720), but his main problem was solved.

I cannot figure out what whats the problem.

**Here is the code to reproduce this issue.**
https://github.com/joselrodrigues/docker-react-native

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12

EXPOSE 19000
EXPOSE 19001
EXPOSE 19002
EXPOSE 19006

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/ReactNative

#install latest yarn
RUN curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
#Add expo-cli globaly
RUN yarn global add expo-cli
#install all react-native dependencies
RUN yarn install
CMD yarn start
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services: 
    reactnative:
        build: 
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        container_name: reactNative
        environment:
            - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0
            - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
        ports:
            - "19000:19000"
            - "19001:19001"
            - "19002:19002"
            - "19006:19006"
        volumes: 
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - node_modules:/usr/src/app/ReactNative/node_modules
volumes: 
    node_modules:
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error with my http://localhost:19002/ starting at a black screen.

What helped was to update my expo cli with `npm install -g expo-cli` and then start again my project with `npm start`.

I updated to expo@3.21.9. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer was really helpful, I was struggling with the black expo screen while I was practicing React Native. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: For me it works after run>> npm install expo-dev-client